# Assign a value to an internal variable in a function angular2

Tags: json, function, angular

I have the following service in Angular2:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService{

    private myServiceUrl= ....

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getService(): Promise<MyObject> {
        return this.http.get(this.myServiceUrl).map(response => response.json())
            .toPromise();
    }    
}
```

And I have this function in one of my components:

```
myFunction(): any{
    let toReturn: any;
    this.myService.getService().then(result => toReturn = result);
    console.log(toReturn);
    return toReturn;
  }
```

Basically, as you can see, I want to store in toReturn, the objects that it is returned by the promise of myService. I am looking to the rest call I have, and I am getting the proper json, but when I am trying to store it in the internal variable, I get undefinied in toReturn.

However, if I try this:

```
this.myService.getService().then(result=> console.log(result));
```

**I am able to see the json I want.**

I can do a function like this:

```
getService(address: string) {
        this.myService.getService().then(result=> this.result= result);
}
```

But I prefer to make my function to return an object. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `getService` is asynchronous, so when your code reaches the line

```
return toReturn;
```

The `toReturn` variable has not yet received the data coming from the server.

The cleanest way to deal with this is to return the promise itself, so that the calling code will extract the data when it arrives from the server:

```
myFunction(): Promise<MyObject> 
{
    //return the promise that will output data in the future
    return this.myService.getService();
}
```

The calling code can access the data this way:

```
myFunction().then( result =>
    this.result= result
)
```

You can even remove a step by getting rid of `myFunction` because it's just a thin wrapper around `getService()`.  Instead the calling code can simply do:

```
this.myService.getService().then(result => this.result = result)
```

And that's it.

**Addendum to address your comments**:

You must understand two concepts about asynchronous ops and promises:

1. *A promise is executed in a different thread*, so the lines after the call to `getService()` are executed *before* the data arrives. That's why `console.log()` doesn't show you data at that point. That's also why trying to return the result there doesn't work
2. *the only place in code where you can capture the result of a promise is .then()*.  There you can do whatever you want with the result, including storing it in any variable. Just remember point 1 above, and don't expect to have access to the result on the very next line because `then()` occurs later in time on a different thread.

> assign the json that comes from that service (which returns a
>   promise), to an internal variable that I defined in the line above, it
>   is not working. How can store it to an internal variable and return it

You cannot.

Comment: AFAIR geodcoding API is also not covered by zone.js and would need a `zone.run(...)` for the code in the function to run inside Angulars zone.

Comment: The promise is return by the googleMapGeocodingService, so I am not accesing to the Promise.

Comment: Guys, forget about geocoding, let's put another name to the service, the service is working... what it is not working is the assignment to an internal variable. If I do geocoding => console.log(geocoding) I can see the complete JSON.

Comment: @Manuelarte what do you mean? You are accessing the promise because it is on the promise that you execute `.then(geocoding...)`. And why the downvote?

Comment: I mean that, this.googleMapGeocodingService.getGeocoding(address).then(geocoding => toReturn = geocoding.results[0].geometry.location);

assign the json that comes from that service (which returns a promise), to an internal variable that I defined in the line above, it is not working. How can store it to an internal variable and return it.

Comment: You cannot store it at the moment you're calling `getGeocoding` because that function is asynchronous. I gave you 2 working options: 1: return the promise that you received from the service (I showed you how and how to extract its data), 2: execute a callback when the data arrives.  You will not be able to return the result immediately as you're trying to do because the result has not arrived yet when the JS engine gets to your `return` line.

Comment: I edited it. I removed that I am calling to a Google Api, because it is information that it is not needed. And I add the Service to show that I am returning a promise, and I want to use the data of that promise.

Comment: @Manuelarte if you downvoted the answer you should take it back. You clearly have no idea what async execution means and I think the answer is fine. The result is not yet available where you have your `console.log()`. When the result becomes available `result => toReturn = result` is called by the promise. Your `myFunction()` was completed loooooong before that.

Comment: Then, I have myService.getService which returns a promise, and I have myFunction which also returns a promise? Then, when can I use the data?

Comment: Inside `then(...)`. You can put as much code there as you want.

Comment: @Manuelarte I showed you how to use the data.  I've updated my answer to match your edited question.  Basically, you call `.then()` on the return value of `myFunction()`. The data arrives inside the `then()`.  Take another look at my answer; especially the part that says: "*the calling code can access the data this way*". PS: i've edited the end of my answer to simplify things a bit.

Comment: You removed one useless step of returning again a Promise. But, you are saving the result in an internal variable, if you try to store it in an external variable, it does not work.

Comment: @Manuelarte honestly I'm not sure how else to help; maybe someone other than me or Gunther can explain better. I added a bit at the bottom of my answer as a last attempt to explain why you cannot do what you want the way you want. If you downvoted my answer, I would still like to know why please.

Comment: Anyway thanks for your answers. I removed the internal, and substituted it for a field (this.geocoding) and now it is working.